# Difference between SharePoint Integration mode and Native mode in SSRS

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, reporting-services

In SharePoint 2013, which one is best practise to configure Reporting Services in `SharePoint Integration mode` or `Native mode`?

Based on which consideration we can choose? Which mode is best and what are the difference between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're using SharePoint already...

The two modes are:

- Native mode, including native mode with SharePoint Web Parts - the report server runs as an application server that provides all processing and management capability exclusively through Reporting Services components.
- SharePoint integrated mode - the report server is deployed as part of
  a SharePoint server farm.

In SharePoint integrated mode, reports are stored in SharePoint, and if that's the place that people within the organisation go for information, then SharePoint is a logical place to store these reports and for users to access these reports. If you're using native mode, then the user has to be directed to the Reporting Services instance to view their reports. It's worth noting that there's a performance hit running Reporting Services in SharePoint integrated mode.

Check out the additional features that are supported by running Reporting Services in SharePoint integrated mode at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326290

Comment: its better idea to deploy  reporting service in an existing sharepoint application rather than prepare new server and install sharepoint and configure reporting services

Comment: That's an 'it depends' question unfortunately! If you require high availability, then run the Reporting Services service on two or more servers in the farm. Where you store the reports should really be a function of where the users want to be accessing them.